# pasar imagenes desde firebase a pdfmake

Tags: nodejs, firebase

Buenas estoy usando pdfmake en mi backend para hacer un pdf con fotos, pero no consigo pasar las fotos desde firebase al pdfmake en el backend, dejo foto del código.

```
let docDefinition = {
    content : [
        'Hello World',
        {
        image: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,/https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/ttrabajo-a4359.appspot.com/o/photosCal%2FCalentador%20Instalado?alt=media&token=9786e6b6-6ecb-4bac-b105-dce2f5c3a8c2',
        width: 100
        }
    ]
};

const printer = new PdfPrinter(fonts);

let pdfDoc = printer.createPdfKitDocument(docDefinition);
pdfDoc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream("pdfs/pdfTest.pdf"));
pdfDoc.end();
```

});

module.exports = router;

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez sea algo tarde pero dejo esto para el futuro, lo que aplique fue instalar Jimp:

> npm i jimp

Lo converti a base64, he hice merge con mi estructura del apartado content de mi pdf. Este es un ejemplo con varias imágenes que debía de agregar, se debe considerar que el array de images, es un array que contiene las urls de mis imagenes ubicadas en el Storage Firebase:

```
    let imagesBase64 = [];

    await solution.images.reduce(async function (previousPromise, img, index) {
      await previousPromise;
      const imgBase64 = await Jimp.read(img)
        .then(image=>  image.resize(Jimp.AUTO, 100).getBase64Async(Jimp.AUTO));
      imagesBase64.push(imgBase64); 
    }, Promise.resolve());

    await imagesBase64.reduce(async function (previousPromise, img, index) {
        await previousPromise;
        const obj = {
          image: img,
          alignment: 'center'
        };
        pdf.content.push(obj); // <--- En este punto se agrega la imagen al PDF
      }, Promise.resolve());
```